# Alternative for Tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

Is there an alternative software or any library in Python or OpenCV that can be an alternative for Tesseract for Character Recognition?

Any suggested methods for Character Recognition that can be implemented with Python?

Thanks

Comment: Please check https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This [site](https://github.com/kba/awesome-ocr#python) lists some libraries and ideas that can be used for OCR in python. According to it and to my knowledge, besides Tesseract, the other possibilty would be Cuneiform.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I'll read more about Cuneiform