# pytesseract does not extract numbers from image

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract numbers from an image using pytesseract but it does not return any text. Here is my code.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
im = Image.open('time.png')

custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789"'# -c preserve_interword_spaces=0'
text= pytesseract.pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config=custom_oem_psm_config)
print(text)
```

**Here is my image**

[image: time]

**Here is the output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pyteserract is not able to extract from all images.

It is mostly able to extract text which is similar to normal fonts we use on Microsoft word, notepad, etc.

Comment: what should I use for fonts like those shown in the above image??

Comment: @JAMSHAID The sample images that pyteserract can extract can be found in this [link](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/tree/master/tests/data).

Unfortunately, the image you are trying is not possible

Comment: is there any other library I can use for it?

Comment: @JAMSHAID You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61241216/13779320